# What is mean by ILogger and IActionResult in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am currently learning ASP.NET MVC and I am having problem on understanding some syntax. Please explain me correctly what this syntax means.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Mypage()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
```

So here what is meant by `private readonly ILogger` ? And what is meant by `IActionResult`? What is the use of that things? Can anyone please explain me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too broad, so here is the breakdown,

**_logger** is property of your Controller, an *object* of *type* that implements *ILogger* interface. Basically it is used for **logging** purpose, besides this it is decorated as *private* and *readonly*

Similarly, **IActionResult** is an interface and return type of this interface allows you to return an object of any *type* that implements this interface. (for ex., ActionResult, JsonResult, ViewResult etc.)

No offence but if you are new to Programming world or C#, Please try to understand,

1. Interfaces
2. Classes/Types
3. Access Modifiers

Getting hold of basics will help you to understand complex things. Same like in language you know words you can construct sentences.

Comment: Thank you very much for you respond, Yes you are correct I am new to c# programming. Can you recommend me more things to learn and sources to learn please?